# Why is the virtual keyword needed?

Tags: c++, virtual

In other words, why doesn't the compiler just "know" that if the definition of a function is changed in a derived class, and a pointer to dynamically allocated memory of that derived class calls the changed function, then that function in particular should be called and not the base class's?

In what instances would not having the virtual keyword work to a programmer's benefit?

Comment: Benefit of not using `virtual`? No overhead!

Comment: Not sure I have the definite answer, but the presence of any virtual keywords means a virtual pointer table will be established at runtime, something which probably has a small performance hit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: Note: a derived class allocated on the stack will still invoke `virtual` functions normally, dynamic or automatic allocation is an **orthogonal** concept to dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`virtual` keyword tells the compiler to implement **dynamic dispatch**.That is how the language was designed.
Without such an keyword the compiler would not know whether or not to implement dynamic dispatch.

The downside of `virtual` or dynamic dispatch in general is that,

- It has slight performance penalty. Most compilers would implement dynamic dispatch using vtable and vptr mechanism, where the appropriate function to call is decided through vtable and hence an additional indirection is needed in case of dynamic dispatch.
- It makes your class Non-POD.

Comment: Virtual functions have an "overhead" compared with non-virtual functions in the same sense that binary search is faster then Quicksort. The comparison is meaningless, because they do different things. If you need dynamic dispatch, you either use a virtual function, or you implement your own dynamic dispatching mechanism, which will be just as "slow" as a virtual function.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I agree to the notion, horses for courses.If you need dynamic dispatch functionality you pay a little performance for the functionality as compared to normal statically bound functions. Agreed, its a bit like comparing apples and pears.

Comment: I prefer apples, by the way ;)

Answer (score 2):

One reason:

Consider base classes located in separate module, like library.

And derived classes in your application.

How would compiler knows during compiling the library that the given function is/must be virtual.

Comment: I think this is the answer that best targets the OP's question. The compiler cannot *guess* whether a method will be used *virtually* or not at the moment it compiles the class.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main designing principles of C++ is that [C++ does not incur overhead for features that are not used (the "zero-overhead principle")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++#Philosophy). This is because of a focus on high performance

This is why you need to opt in to features like virtual functions while in languages like Java, functions are virtual by default.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know, because it can't. It might be your intention, to not use virtual functions, because there's always a cost associated with every feature.

Comment: You really have to pay something for what you want. Something has to give.